# .click not working for dynamically loaded form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form which displays images that are currently stored in my database.Upon retrieving the filepaths, it is then dynamically loaded into the form together with a "Delete" `<button>`, which will allow the user to delete the image via an AJAX call.

I am currently able to load the image and the button successfully, but the button will not call the ajax function on click.

I'm using `.on('click')` on the parent container but it's still not working.

```
jQuery Code(Extract):

$('#ItemDetailsContainer').on('change',function(){

    // Deletes Existing pics
    $('#ImageDelete1').on('click',function(){
        DeleteImage1();
    });

});
```

Code for the AJAX function:

```
function DeleteImage1() {

    var itemid=$('#ImageDeleteItemID2').val();
    var filepath=$('#ImageDeleteFilePath2').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"deleteitempic.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"ItemID="+itemid+"&FilePath="+filepath,
        success:function(){
            alert("Image successfully deleted.");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Image could not be deleted due to an error.");
        }
    });
};
```

HTML(extract):

```
<form id='BizEditItem' name='BizEditItemDetails' method='post' action='edititemprocess.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' novalidate='novalidate'>

    <div class='BizEditItemDetail'>
        <label for='BizEditItemCat'>Category:</label>
        <select class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemCat' name='BizEditItemCat'></select>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div class='BizEditItemDetail'>
        <label for='BizEditItemSubCat'>SubCategory:</label>
        <select class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemSubCat' name='BizEditItemSubCat'></select>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div class='BizEditItemDetail'>
        <label for='BizEditItemOld'>Item:</label>
        <select class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemOld' name='BizEditItemOld'></select>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div id='ItemDetailsContainer'>
    </div>

</form>
```

Dynamically Loaded part(extract):

```
echo"<div class='BizAddItemDetails' >";
//Counter variable to track images displayed
$imgdisplayed=1;

while($getimage=$fetchimg->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $filepath=$getimage['FilePath'];
    echo"<label for='BizEditItemFile1'>Upload Image &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp(Max Size:2MB)</label>";
    echo"<input type='file' class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemFile$imgdisplayed' name='BizEditItemFiles[]' />";
    echo"<span></span>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<img id=\"ImagePreview$imgdisplayed\" name=\"ImagePreview$imgdisplayed\" class='ImagePreview' src=\"$filepath\" > ";
    echo"<input type='hidden' name=\"ImageDeleteItemID$imgdisplayed\" value=\"$itemid\">";
    echo"<input type='hidden' name=\"ImageDeleteFilePath$imgdisplayed\" value=\"$filepath\" >";
    echo"<input type='button' id=\"ImageDelete$imgdisplayed\" name=\"ImageDelete$imgdisplayed\" class='ImageDeleteButton' value='Delete Picture'>";
    echo"name=\"ImageDelete$imgdisplayed\"";

    $imgdisplayed++;
}

while($imgdisplayed<=3) {
    echo"<label for='BizEditItemFile1'>Upload Image</label>";
    echo"<input type='file' class='BizEditItemInput' id='BizEditItemFile$imgdisplayed' name='BizEditItemFiles[]' />";
    echo"<span></span>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<img id=\"ImagePreview$imgdisplayed\" name=\"ImagePreview$imgdisplayed\" class='EmptyImagePreview' > ";
    echo"<br>";
    $imgdisplayed++;
}
echo"</div>";
```

Things tried:

I've tried using

```
$('#ImageDelete1').click(function(){
    DeleteImage1();
});
```

instead, as well as changing the AJAX call to a simple alert but nothing is working.

There also also no errors whatsoever in both the server error logs AND chrome's console.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you'll need to bind to the document rather than the individual element:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ImageDelete1',function(){
    DeleteImage1();
});
```

This is just the top-level issue; there may be an underlying issue with your system. The reason why it's important to [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/) when using Ajax is because when you update the DOM (removing the bound element), Javascript loses its "bind" it had on the original object, thus preventing it from performing the required update. Delegating from document fixes this

Comment: Thx for taking the time to reply Rich, What do you mean by top-level issue,and underlying issue with my system? Is there any way for me to check my system for problems?(I'm currently using localhost)

Comment: I meant that although what I recommended will work if you directly replace the element in question, you may have a deeper issue with your system which I have not picked up on. Essentially, I just saw your issue & gave an answer which has worked for me countless times -- but there may be another problem, that's all!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue multiple times.

Add the click event inside the while loops after the image has been created.

```
echo "<script>$('#ImageDelete1').click(function(){ DeleteImage1(); });</scipt>";
```

Hope this helps.